# How to decorate a date range filter with a date picker in SONATA ADMIN

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I want to have a date picker for one my 'date range' filters but instead i have a choice type for different part of my date when I'm using this code:

```
$datagridMapper->add('movementDate','doctrine_orm_date_range')
```

and I had this result:

[image: default date range filter in Sonata]

So how can I make it display a date picker?

Answer (score 1):

```
$datagridMapper->add('movementDate','doctrine_orm_date_range',[
                'field_type'=>'sonata_type_date_range_picker',
                'field_options' => [
                    'field_options' => [
                        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                    ]
                ]
            ])
```

Comment: this was possible in the earlier version of sonata not the newest ones, the 'sonata_type_date_range_picker' type doesn't exist anymore

Comment: which version of symfony you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $datagridMapper->add('movementDate', DateRangeFilter::class,[
                'field_type'=> DateRangePickerType::class,
                'field_options' => [
                    'field_options' => [
                        'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy'
                    ]
                ]
            ])
```

Comment: While this code might answer the OP's question, you could make your answer much better by appending an explanation on how your code solves the problem